# phonegap displaying text in native textbox

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm making an android app which uses bluetooth using phonegap and I'm having issues handling code because it get's called every 100ms.
I want to try if the issue occurs because my phonegap javascript code is to long causing delays.
To try this I want to dispaly the received message using a native textbox.
Is this possible? and How would I do this?

Thanks

Martijn

PS: I've tried using Toast but since I want to change the displayed value every 100ms this doesn't work.

Code

upon receiving a message this is the order the code is processed

```
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
s_message = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
String[] strArray = s_message.split(",");                   
mHandleReceivedThread = new HandleReceivedThread(strArray);  
mHandleReceivedThread.start();
```

In the HandleReceivedThread:

```
if(strArrayReceived[0].startsWith("Pressure"))
{
if(strArrayReceived[1].contains("Pressure"))
{
double Pressure = Double.parseDouble(strArrayReceived[1].replace("Pressure", ""));
double PressureResult = Pressure/10; 
String PressureValue = String.valueOf(PressureResult);
webView.sendJavascript("PressureValue = " + Pressure + ";");
webView.sendJavascript("document.getElementById('Pressure').innerHTML = " + PressureValue + ";");                                           
Log.e(TAG, "Message fail: " + strArrayReceived[1] );
}
else
{
double Pressure = Double.parseDouble(strArrayReceived[1]
double PressureResult = Pressure/10; 
String PressureValue = String.valueOf(PressureResult);
webView.sendJavascript("PressureValue = " + Pressure + ";");
webView.sendJavascript("document.getElementById('Pressure').innerHTML = " + PressureValue + ";");                                    
}
}
```

this is basically what happens.
And this happens every 100ms , and for some reason the displaying of the Value has lag and sometimes the received message (which should be "Pressure,1500" , or a different value) is Pressure,1500Pressure , causing errors (which I've managed to fix). but this still isn't optimal.
The message is send correctly and if I use a simple chat app they are received correctly.

if there is anything else I should supply , just ask ;-)

Comment: It doesn't sound like using a native textbox is the solution to the problem you describe. I am not sure what the solutions is, but I am certain it is not that!

Comment: I know it won't be the solution, but if I can display the message in a simple native textbox I can see if the delay still occurs. If it does there is a different problem. If it doesn't I know it's the javascript. Or at least thats my theorie ;-)

Comment: It's difficult to provide a solution when we don't know exactly what the problem is. Perhaps you can provide us some code snippets so we can work out what exactly are you are trying to do, and what the problem is with it.

Comment: I've added parts of my code to my original post.